# How do I loop this Dice Game so that it plays for five rounds? (Python GCSE)

Tags: python, project

I'm currently working on my OCR GCSE Program. I'm a new developer and this is my most extensive project yet.

The basis for the code is there, the program is working as intended, however my brief asks that the program run 5 times over for five separate rounds.

I'm struggling to understand while loops, whenever I try to implement a while loop. The program can not go past the login system.

I need some help figuring out how to loop this program and any suggestions on how to improve and optimise the code would be greatly appreciated! :) - Jayode18

```
import random

# Login system redone 19/11/18

user = ("user")
passw = ("pass")

userName = input("Please enter your username: ")
if userName == user:


 print("\n")
    print("Username correct!")

else:
    print("Username incorrect!")
    quit()

print("\n")

passWord = input("Now please enter your password: ")
if passWord == passw:
    print("\n")
    print("User access granted! Game will now begin")
    print("\n")

else:
    print("Invalid Credentials")
    quit()

# Bug Update 19/11/18: Rewrote Login System. Bug fixed.

# Dice game rules / To Do list
# - Dice total added to score. - DONE
# - if total = even + 10 to score - DONE
# - if total = odd - 5 to score - DONE
# - if roll = double roll + 1 die and add roll to score - Simple if statement. Check if dice1 == dice2 and if yes then roll a third dice - DONE
# - Score != < 0 - DONE
# - Score after 5 rolls wins. - Learn while loops. IN PROGRESS 
# - if p1score == p2score roll 1 die and see who wins - Same as doubles. Just check scores after 5 rounds, and roll a third if need be. Repeat until win.
# Save all scores at the end of every round and add to finalScorep1 & p2 variable. Compare these and whichever is higher, print winners name and highest roll. 

# Ask both players for their names and store them locally to a file

p1Name = input("Player 1. Please enter your name: ")
p2Name = input("Player 2. Please enter your name: ")

f=open("Player1_Data.txt" , "a")
f.write("Player Name: " + p1Name + "\n")
f.close()

f=open("Player2_Data.txt" , "a")
f.write("Player Name: " + p2Name + "\n")
f.close()
print("\n")

# Ask if player 1 would like to roll their dice, and if yes, then roll them.
player1Roll = input(p1Name + " would you like to roll your dice? Y/N: ")
print("\n")


# Credit to StackOveflow. (Finding User later) (Haha)
if player1Roll ==("Y"):
    for x in range (1):
        print ("You rolled a:")
        Dice1 = int(random.randint(1,6))
        print(Dice1)

    for x in range (1):
        print ("You rolled a:")
        Dice2 = int(random.randint(1,6))
        print(Dice2)


diceTotalp1 = Dice1 + Dice2

score = diceTotalp1

oddScore = int(score) - 5 

scoreZero = int(0)

evenScore = int(score) + 10

if score == int(2):
        print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
        score + 10
        score = evenScore

elif score == int(4):
         print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
         score + 10
         score = evenScore

elif score == int(6):
         print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
         score + 10
         score = evenScore

elif score == int(8):
         print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
         score + 10
         score = evenScore

elif score == int(10):
         print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
         score + 10
         score = evenScore
elif score == int(12):
         print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
         score + 10
         score = evenScore

elif score == int(3):
    print("Aww. You rolled an odd number. - 5 points.")
    score - 5
    score = oddScore

elif score == int(5):
    print("Aww. You rolled an odd number. - 5 points.")
    score - 5
    score = oddScore


elif score == int(7):
    print("Aww. You rolled an odd number. - 5 points.")
    score - 5
    score = oddScore

elif score == int(9):
    print("Aww. You rolled an odd number. - 5 points.")
    score - 5
    score = oddScore


elif score == int(11):
    print("Aww. You rolled an odd number. - 5 points.")
    score - 5
    score = oddScore

elif score == int(0):
    print("Your score is already 0! It can't go any lower. That's just mean")
    score + 0


if score == int(0):
    print("Your score is already 0! It can't go any lower. That's just mean")
    score + 0

# If Player 1 rolls double, roll a third dice and add it to their score
if Dice1 == Dice2:
    print("\n")
    print("Congratulations! You rolled a double. Here's a bonus roll.")
    for x in range (1):
        print("You rolled a:")
        bonusDice = int(random.randint(1,6))
        print(bonusDice)

        bonusScore = score + bonusDice
        score = bonusScore




# Note to self: Remind that 2 other methods were attempted before settling on if/elif.
# 1. Creating a variable that had all the even/odd numbers in them respectively, Outcome: Wouldn't work
# 2. On launch, writing a list of all the even/odd numbers to a local file. And then reading that local file where appropriate.
# Outcome: Could read and print the list, but could not read and apply them to an if statement.

# Shows the players what Player 1's final score for the round is     
print("\n")
print(p1Name + "'s score for round 1 is: " + str (score))
print("\n")

# Write Player 1's total for this round to a local file
f=open("Player1_Data.txt" , "a")
f.write("Round 1 Total Roll: " + str (diceTotalp1) + ("\n"))
f.close()

# Write Player 1's final score for the round to a local file
f=open("Player1_Data.txt" , "a")
f.write("Round 1 Score: " + str (score) + ("\n")) 
f.close()

# Ask player 2 if they would like to roll, and if yes, then roll them.
player2Roll = input(p2Name + " would you like to roll your dice? Y/N: ")
print("\n")
if player2Roll ==("Y"):
    for x in range (1):
        print ("You rolled a:")
        dice1 = int(random.randint(1,6))
        print(dice1)

    for x in range (1):
        print ("You rolled a:")
        dice2 = int(random.randint(1,6))
        print(dice2)

diceTotalp2 = dice1 + dice2

scorep2 = diceTotalp2

oddScorep2 = int(scorep2) - 5 

scoreZerop2 = int(0)

evenScorep2 = int(scorep2) + 10

if scorep2 == int(2):
        print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
        scorep2 + 10
        scorep2 = evenScorep2

elif scorep2 == int(4):
         print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
         scorep2 + 10
         scorep2 = evenScorep2

elif scorep2 == int(6):
         print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
         scorep2 + 10
         scorep2 = evenScorep2

elif scorep2 == int(8):
         print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
         scorep2 + 10
         scorep2 = evenScorep2

elif scorep2 == int(10):
         print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
         scorep2 + 10
         scorep2 = evenScorep2
elif scorep2 == int(12):
         print("You rolled an even number + 10 points!")
         scorep2 + 10
         scorep2 = evenScorep2

elif scorep2 == int(3):
    print("Aww. You rolled an odd number. - 5 points.")
    scorep2 = oddScorep2

elif scorep2 == int(5):
    print("Aww. You rolled an odd number. - 5 points.")
    scorep2 = oddScorep2


elif scorep2 == int(7):
    print("Aww. You rolled an odd number. - 5 points.")
    scorep2 = oddScorep2

elif scorep2 == int(9):
    print("Aww. You rolled an odd number. - 5 points.")
    scorep2 = oddScorep2


elif scorep2 == int(11):
    print("Aww. You rolled an odd number. - 5 points.")
    scorep2 = oddScorep2

elif scorep2 == int(0):
    print("Your score is already 0! It can't go any lower. That's just mean")
    scorep2 + 0

# If Player 2 rolls a double, roll a bonus die and add it to their score.
if dice1 == dice2:
    print("\n")
    print("Congratulations! You rolled a double. Here's a bonus roll.")
    for x in range (1):
        print("You rolled a:")
        bonusDicep2 = int(random.randint(1,6))
        print(bonusDicep2)

        bonusScorep2 = scorep2 + bonusDicep2
        scorep2 = bonusScorep2

# Shows the players what Player 2's final score for the round is.
print("\n")
print(p2Name + "'s score for round 1 is: " + str (scorep2))

# Write Player 2's roll for this round to a local file
f=open("Player2_Data.txt" , "a")
f.write("Round 1 Total Roll: " + str(diceTotalp2)+ ("\n"))
f.close()

f=open("Player2_Data.txt" , "a")
f.write("Round 1 Total Score: " + str(scorep2))
f.close()
```

Comment: Do you need all those elif statements? You can use `score % 2` to check if a number is even or odd (`%` means modulo, meaning it will give the remainder when `score` is divided by `2` for the example, 1 when score is odd, 0 when score is even)

Comment: The login system should not even be part of the loop (unless you want the user to log in at the start of *every* round). While loops are a very basic concept, so it would be worthwhile to read a tutorial or a good Python book.

Comment: I'll give that a go! Thanks very much! @Max

Comment: Also, use functions! This avoids repetitive code; such as when you are writing to Player1_Data.txt and Player2_Data.txt. This makes your code less, easier to read and also helps you out when you need to loop the game; i.e. if you have your main game inside a function called `game()`, then you can just do `for i in range(5): game()`

Comment: @meowgoesthedog. It isn't part of the loop. However for some reason, when I write a while loop, it seems to cut the program off after the player's sign in.

Comment: Then you should show the while loop that you tried. Without it there is no way for us to know what went wrong.

Comment: Also... `for x in range (1):` doesn't do anything. Unless you're going to change it later so that it runs more than once, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at this:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

The for statement will solve your problem! You just need to put all the code you want to be looped inside of it, like this:

```
for i in range(5):
    print('Number {}'.format(i))
```

In this example above, the programm output will be like:

```
Number 0
Number 1
Number 2
Number 3
Number 4
```

In other words, the code was looped 5 times! And the variable i are the number of the iteration.

Hope I've helped!